# ChildProcess::TimeoutError: process still alive after 90 seconds when running cucumber features

Tags: cucumber, selenium-webdriver

When I try to run Cucumber features on my ci-server. It fails with following error

```
ChildProcess::TimeoutError: process still alive after 90 seconds
```

It works fine on my local machine.

About gems and browser, Im using selenium-webdriver(2.30.0), capybara(2.0.2) and cucumber(1.2.2) and Firefox 19.0

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Does Firefox work OK when you start it manually on the ci-server? You might have better luck with capybara-webkit, since it runs without actually opening a browser window.

Comment: Yes, Firefox start on server. Im using Xvfb to run firefox on background.

Comment: +1. Got some problem with firefox + ubuntu + Xvfb.